# Theme Options wp_editor breaks with 6.0.2 update

Tags: theme-options, wp-editor, upgrade

I'm in the process of migrating my sites to a new server (windows -> nginx). One of my old themes has 4 options pages. One of the options pages includes 3 wp_editor instances. However, all 4 options pages are now displaying 3 broken Tiny MCE editors above the normal options page. On the options page with the 3 wp_editor instances, there are still wp_editor instances in the location where they should be but they are broken (not displaying the text that should be present). I'm assuming with the move to Gutenburg that there have been changes to wp_editor that I've been unable to find and hoping you all can point me in the right direction.

Currently, in my functions.php I have the following code:

```
    function x_theme_admin_styles() {
    wp_editor( "" , "main_text", array());
    wp_editor( "" , "invite", array());
    wp_editor( "" , "mobilemain_text", array());
    wp_enqueue_script('word-count');
    wp_enqueue_script('post');
    wp_enqueue_script('editor');
    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
    }
```

Then the options page calls the 3 editors as follows:

```
    wp_editor($x_maincont_opt['x_main_text'], "main_text", array());
    wp_editor($x_maincont_opt['x_invite'], "invite", array());
    wp_editor($x_maincont_opt['x_mobilemain_text'], "mobilemain_text", array());
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

Remove the following lines of code from the functions.php

```
    wp_editor( "" , "main_text", array());
    wp_editor( "" , "invite", array());
    wp_editor( "" , "mobilemain_text", array());
```

Shoutout to @aatanasov on wordpress.org/support for the solution.